# Is there any more efficient way to code this "2 Sum" Questions

Tags: javascript

Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.

The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 < index2. Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2 ) are not zero-based.
Put both these numbers in order in an array and return the array from your function ( Looking at the function signature will make things clearer ). Note that, if no pair exists, return empty list.

If multiple solutions exist, output the one where index2 is minimum. If there are multiple solutions with the minimum index2, choose the one with minimum index1 out of them.

```js
twoSum : function(A, B){
        var tempA = A;
        var index1 = [];
        var index2 = [];
        var Results = [];
        var diff = A.length/2;
        
        for(var i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++){
            var temp = B - A[i];
            for(var j = i; j < A.length - 1; j++){
                if(temp == A[j]){
                    if(j - i > 0){
                        if(j < Results[1] || Results.length == 0){
                      if(A[j] != A[Results[1]-1] && A[i] != A[Results[0]-1]){
                       Results[0] = i + 1;
                             Results[1] = j + 1; 
                      }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Results;
    }
```

Comment: Please post this on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you have some example of arrays and the wanted result? btw, why are indices not zero based?

Comment: You could start by not calculating and storing variables you don't use.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah, the return result are not zero based, depend on the questions i got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a single loop approach with an object to store missing values.

```js
function find(array, sum) {
    var hash = {},
        i = 0;
        
    while (i < array.length) {
        const value = array[i++];
        if (value in hash) return [hash[value], i];
        if (!(sum - value in hash)) hash[sum - value] = i;
    }
}

console.log(find([2, 4, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 3, 4], 8));
```